# How to permanently save data in a plist

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I need to save some simple application settings and choose to use plist.

After searching stackoverflow and other resources I found that the most used pattern is to read and write using a dictionary.
So I'm trying to save app configuration data in a plist, but they are not permanently saved.

This is the code implemented for the button "Save configuration"
(of course there is a "config.plist" file with a "initialURL" key)

```
- (IBAction) saveButtonTapped
{
    NSString *plistfile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"config" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict =[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistfile];
    [dict setValue:initialURL.text forKey:@"initialURL"];
    [dict writeToFile:plistfile atomically:YES];
}
```

After writeToFile:plistfile, the value that was written in the UITextField named initialURL is writen in the right key, and if reload the same key i get the updated value, but if I exit the application and restart it, the value of initialURL is lost.

Why this happens? Is there anything wrong in expecting that "writeToFile" does actually writes to a file (for me a file is permanent storage, if i write to a file data is stored permanently).

Francesco

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
[dict setValue:initialURL.text forKey:@"initialURL"];
```

to

```
[dict setObject:initialURL.text forKey:@"initialURL"];
```

Also you cannot write to your bundle, you need to copy the file to the application's document folder.

Comment: Can you please briefly explain what do you mean by "copy the file..."?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132005/iphone-copying-a-file-from-resources-to-documents-gives-an-error. This is because you cannot change your bundle at runtime, only access files from it.

Comment: I think I now understand what you say; can you point me to some resource for learnig how to deal with files and the application's document folder? Thanks a lot

Comment: Look at the NSFileManager (you can use this method: - (BOOL)copyItemAtPath:(NSString *)srcPath toPath:(NSString *)dstPath error:(NSError **)error) and "Low-Level File Management Programming Topics", you can get the document folder path like this NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

Answer (score 0):

You could use NSUserDefaults to store settings if it's config settings and suchlike.  [You can read about it here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

Copy the config.plist to Documents folder once the very first time your app runs.

```
NSString *plistfile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"config" ofType:@"plist"];
NSString* documentPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:plistfile toPath:documentPath error:nil];
```

Then to access

```
- (IBAction) saveButtonTapped
{
    NSString *plistfile = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]] pathForResource:@"config" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict =[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistfile];
    [dict setValue:initialURL.text forKey:@"initialURL"];
    [dict writeToFile:plistfile atomically:YES];
}
```