# Can't write to document directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I'm trying to copy a `json` file from the application bundle to the `Document` directory, but surprisingly i'm not able to do that. Here's the code:

```
NSArray *array = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docDir = [array lastObject];
NSString *path   = [docDir stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"themes.json"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
   {
     NSString *themesPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"themes" ofType:@"json"];
     NSError  *error      = nil;

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:themesPath toPath:path error:&error];

     if (error)
        NSLog(@"Error %@", error);
  }
```

It produces the following error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 513.)" UserInfo=0x194a0e90 {NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/var/mobile/Applications/ACED3EF9-B0D8-49E8-91DE-37128357E509/Frinder.app/themes.json, NSUserStringVariant=(
>       Copy
>   ), NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Applications/ACED3EF9-B0D8-49E8-91DE-37128357E509/Frinder.app/themes.json, NSDestinationFilePath=/var/mobile/Applications/ACED3EF9-B0D8-49E8-91DE-37128357E509/Documents.themes.json, NSUnderlyingError=0x194a0400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted"}

After a search i've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132005/iphone-copying-a-file-from-resources-to-documents-gives-an-error) and tried to modify my code as follows:

```
 if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
    {
       NSString *themesPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"themes" ofType:@"json"];
       NSData   *data       = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:themesPath];

       BOOL success =  [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:path contents:data attributes:nil];

       if (!success)
          NSLog(@"Fail"); 
    }
```

but it doesn't work either. `success` variable is `NO`. The last thing i tried was:

```
[data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

but still in vain. it returns `NO`.

I need to note that the issue arises on a device only. On a simulator it works all right.
 Can anybody give me a clue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first example is correct on one thing:

```
[docDir stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"themes.json"];
```

should be:

```
[docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"themes.json"];
```

This becomes clear we you read the error message, you see that it tries to write the file to `/var/mobile/Applications/ACED3EF9-B0D8-49E8-91DE-37128357E509/Documents.themes.json`. Notice that there a `.` where there should be a `/`.

The `stringByAppendingPathExtension:` is used for adding a extension to a file, `jpg`, `txt`, `html`,.....

`stringByAppendingPathComponent` will add a file to a path, by adding the correct directory separator, you case `/`.

You second example will definitely fail since the app bundle is readonly.

Comment: @AndreyChernukha Sorry copy past error, I've also added some explanation about the difference between to two methods.

Comment: @rckoenes indeed it worked. Thanks a lot. I'll accept your answer in four minutes

Comment: @AndreyChernukha the simulator is less strict, also it is simulator not an emulator. The simulator is not a good reference for testing. Since it just translates iOS calls to OS X. Always test on a device before sending an app in for review.