# iOS9 NSFileManager asks for permission to save files in Documents directory

Tags: copy, device, nsfilemanager, ios9, beta

For the long time I receive a strange error, but only when running on a device. In simulator everything is just fine. What I do is moving sample files from app bundle directory to Documents directory on a device.
I have tried all those methods for NSFileManager:

```
- (BOOL)copyItemAtPath:(NSString *)srcPath toPath:(NSString *)dstPath error:(NSError **)error
- (BOOL)moveItemAtPath:(NSString *)srcPath toPath:(NSString *)dstPath error:(NSError **)error
- (BOOL)linkItemAtPath:(NSString *)srcPath toPath:(NSString *)dstPath error:(NSError **)error
```

And every one throws errors like following:

> 2015-08-15 23:14:15.152 app[1010:339938] Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "“file.txt” couldn’t be linked because you don’t have permission to access “Documents”." UserInfo={NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/verylongid/fastdict.app/Dictionaries/file.txt, NSUserStringVariant=(
>       Link
>   ), NSDestinationFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/verylongid/Documents/file.txt, NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/verylongid/fastdict.app/Dictionaries/file.txt, NSUnderlyingError=0x13666d5a0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}} in -[AppDelegate fillDirectoryWithSamplesIfEmpty]

How can I solve this problem?

Update: The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1564028/2766161) found here really works!
Good luck!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone - copying a file from resources to Documents gives an error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132005/iphone-copying-a-file-from-resources-to-documents-gives-an-error)

Answer (score 6):

You can't able to move the bundle file to document directory, since you dont have a permission to do.
Try copyItemAtPath
Also Make sure that you are getting the document directory correctly

```
  NSString *fileName = @"LICENSE.txt";
    NSString *sourcePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    NSData *mainBundleFile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:sourcePath];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectoryPath,fileName]
                                            contents:mainBundleFile
                                          attributes:nil];
    NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectoryPath,fileName] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                     error:NULL];
    self.label.text = content;
    NSLog(@"file content = %@",content);
```

The above code works perfectly in iPhone5 device iOS9.0 .
Still problem exists , paste your code snippet

Comment: Its one single line of code. Totally same to what you wrote. You can see the error description in my question post.

Comment: Are you tested in iOS9 beta installed device ?

Comment: Oh god... You answered me three times and every time it seems like you are not reading the question. Take a look at it again! Its an issue with iOS9 (it even has such a tag!). And in post i wrote, that it only occurs on device only, not in simulator... Please, be more watchful.

Comment: @AshotVardanian Ok man.. cool..Just want to reconfirm..cool...Still you didn't post your code snippet... Actually i don't have a iOS9 installed device . Is it working on iOS8.x installed devices ?

Comment: @AshotVardanian updated answer. The code is working perfectly on my iPhone5 iOS9.0 device.