# creating folder in group container

Tags: cocoa

I have to create a folder inside the group container. I have used the following code

```
NSError* error;
BOOL state = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:somepath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
```

The application is a sandboxed application, while executing the above code following error is observed. What could be the solution for this issue?

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513
"You don’t have permission to save the file “somepath” in the folder
“Group Containers”." UserInfo=0x21111c0
{NSFilePath=/Users/admin/Library/Containers/mypath/Data/../../../Group Containers/somepath,
NSUnderlyingError=0x21517c0 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
Operation not permitted"}
```

(Error message is manually wrapped for readability.)

Answer (score 0):

The path looks a little messed up. Can you update your question to include the part where "somepath" is actually created? The reason I asked is because searching for "cocoa 513" comes up with [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912828/how-do-i-fix-cocoa-error-513).